# Storing JSON structure in VueX

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuex

I'm fairly new to Vue/VueX, and I'm researching a solution to store JSONs in the VueX state. At first it seems pretty straightforward:

```
state {
  jsonthing: { ... }
}
```

The problem: getters return `Observer` type, not `Object` type. So I can do this and retrieve the entire JSON structure:

```
getters: {
  getJSON(state) {
    return state.jsonthing;
  }
}
```

But I can't retrieve a node or a single value of the JSON, like this:

```
getters: {
  getOneNode: state =>
    nodeName => {
      return state.jsonthing[nodeName];
    }
  }
}
```

The getter retrieves `state.jsonthing` as an `Observer`. I can't find a way to extract the desired content of the JSON from this `Observer` and return that. I know I can do it in my components using `mapState` but that's not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do it in the getter?

What I'm currently doing is that I store the JSON as a string (`JSON.stringify()`) and convert it back in the getter (`JSON.parse()`). Strings are retrieved as strings, and not `Observers`. It works, but it's a hack.

While we are here, I also can't find any documentation for the `Observer` type. I'd appreciate if someone could drop a URL!

Answer (score 1):

All right guys, you're not very active today, so here is a solution. If you know a better one, please let me know.

**Solution 1:**
Convert the JSON into a string with `JSON.stringify()` and store it as a string. Then the getter converts it back with `JSON.parse()`. This works, but admittedly ugly.

**Solution 2:**
Generate a function that returns the JSON. This is way better.

```
state: {
  jsonthing: null
}
mutations: {
  INITIALIZE(state, jsonthing) {
    state.jsonthing = new Function(`return ${ JSON.stringify(jsonthing) }`)
  }
}
getters: {
  getOneNode: state =>
    nodeName => {
      return state.jsonthing()[nodeName];
    }
  }
}
```

I've written an article on Medium about this method and a practical application (which I'm actually implementing).

https://medium.com/developer-rants/simple-dynamic-localization-in-vue-with-vuex-b429c525cd90